# Makefile: what if a set of targets can be satisfied by calling one program?

Tags: makefile

Let's say that I have a program `generator` that accepts **a list of** filenames with suffixes `.source` and produces one file with suffix `.source` replaced with `.target` for each argument.

I have a set of files with suffixes `.source` and want to write a rule that calls this program **once** for all files that are newer than targets.

I just want to optimise this working Makefile that calls `generator` for each changed source.

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.source)
TARGETS=$(SOURCES:%.source=%.target)

all: $(TARGETS)

%.target : %.source
        ./generator $<
```

This works as required:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.source)

all: target.timestamp

target.timestamp : $(SOURCES)
        ./generator $?
        touch target.timestamp
```

*Can I avoid creating the timestamp file?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by collecting the prerequisites in a list in each recipe
and then doing a roundup operation in a phony target:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.source)
TARGETS=$(SOURCES:%.source=%.target)

all: collective_build

%.target : %.source
    $(eval collective_src += $<)

# we do a cp to update the .target files
collective_build:  $(TARGETS)
    $(foreach f,$(collective_src),cp $(f) $(subst source,target,$(f)); )
```

BUT you are breaking [Pauls rule #2](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) "Every non-.PHONY rule must update a file with the exact name of its target." and are unhinging the very basis of make.

Comment: I believe that's because `make` sees that the `updatetargets` target may be satisfied just from `$(SOURCES)` and does not evaluate the `%.target : %.source` rule.

Comment: Of course only the `.target`files which are out of date are collected in the `$(collective_src)`. I pasted my full test makefile which works for me on GNUmake 4.

Comment: I did not guess that the `collective_build` target should depend on `$(TARGETS)`.  This way it works, thank you.  One small issue is that when everything is up to date, `generator` is still called without arguments, but this can be easily fixed.

Answer (score -1):

make need a timestamp to know if run *generator* or not; but your *generator* build a list of files, so there is no a single timestamp.

You wrote two valid makefiles, with the pros and cons you know, and there is no alternative.

Comment: You made a negative statement (that there is no alternative) without any proof.  BTW, such statements are hard to proof.